# Search Wikipedia for articles containing a special tag

Tags: wikipedia

I'd like to find all Wikipedia articles using the tags `<chem>` and `<math chem>`. [Searching in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=<chem>&title=Special:Search&fulltext=1) does not consider `<` and `>`. How could I achieve my aim?

Comment: Where do you typically find those tags?

Comment: Here is the [documentation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) and I want to know which articles that actually is used in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for specific math tags you can use a regexp `insource:/\<math(.*)\>(.*)\\hat H(.*)\<\/math\>/`[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=insource%3A%2F%5C%3Cmath%28.%2A%29%5C%3E%28.%2A%29%5C%5Chat%20H%28.%2A%29%5C%3C%5C%2Fmath%5C%3E%2F&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=1uxjsyrmlh45vmklj6twkznlh%20insource%20search%20feature).

I wrote a short script that extracts all pages that contain math and chem tags from a wikidump

https://github.com/physikerwelt/wikiFilter

The latest results are here

https://github.com/physikerwelt/wikiMath17/releases

including a list of only the formulae but not the whole page text.

Comment: You should extend the description, answers containing just the links to off-site resources are not considered good. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: The first line is a perfect answer. The rest is just the topping.

Comment: @physikerwelt Do you know how I could search across all languages of Wikipedia with the `insource:` search?

Comment: @mhchem I don't know if that's possible, but I uploaded the dataset with all formulae. Which I got recently from Marko Obrovac.